# How to correctly convert timespec to timeval?

Tags: c++, data-conversion, fuse, timeval, timespec

I have a `struct timespec` object I need to convert to `struct timeval` for use with `lutimes(...)`.

I've attempted the following, but `lutimes()` complains.

```
const struct timespec ts; // originally provided as function parameter from FUSE
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = ts.tv_sec;
tv.tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
lutimes(path, tv); // returns -1; errno=EINVAL
```

Now `EINVAL` from `lutimes` means the usec component was outside of `0 <= tv_usec < 1000000`, meaning the conversion from `timespec` went wrong. [[source]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/835-8003/6ruu1b0re/index.html)

How do I properly convert from `timespec` to `timeval`?

---

More thorough debugging with the `touch` command, reveals that `timespec` contains `tv_sec = 0` and `tv_nsec > 1000000000`, when no specific date was specified and the current time should be used.

Why is this? What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: This code does not compile. The `lutimes` function takes *array of two* `timeval`s as second parameter. You should post your actual code.

Comment: @michalsrb I know, if you actually want to try this just give it the same timeval twice (which should set access time and modification time to the same value). Should I change my example code?

Comment: Better yet show the actual code that gives you the EINVAL error.

Comment: @michalsrb Sure, it's at https://gitlab.com/Cobra_Fast/maidfs/blob/4aa6091c333796ffc041f8fe381128716e970503/maidfs/main.cpp#L1221 and I've managed a workaround since: https://gitlab.com/Cobra_Fast/maidfs/blob/28e13ef589e66c3fa23189375959f279e6eb8f3b/maidfs/main.cpp#L1221 but I'd still like to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll clarify what was not clear to me at first from the question: This is implementation of the `utimens` operation in fuse filesystem and the problem is that sometimes the `tv_nsec` field has value bigger or equal to 1,000,000,000.

My guess is that it is one of the two special values: `UTIME_NOW` or `UTIME_OMIT`.

The fuse documentation points to the `utimensat` manual page, which has explanation for those special values:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html

---

Also check the `nsec_valid` function in linux kernel:

https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15.2/source/fs/utimes.c#L40

Comment: Quality stuff, thanks a ton. Those two constants somehow went past me.